# I need to end my case statement as current date

Tags: mysql

I have a query with a lot of cases. all is working i just need to know how i can end case as curdate()

```
end as concat(year(curdate()),' ',monthname(curdate())),
case when
```

here is the example

```
`2017 - January` + `2017 - February` + `2017 - March`+ `2017 - April` + `2017 - May` + `2017 - June`  + `2017 - July`
 + `2017 - August`+ `2017 - September` + `2017 - October`    + `2017 - November`  + `2017 - December` AS '2017'
```

now i need the AS '2017' to be as year(curdate()-1)
ihave no idea how to do this

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: When randomly typing words no longer meets your requirement, you can always try [reading the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html).

Comment: not a usefull answer is it?

Comment: You could consider using the DATEADD function - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp

Comment: See below - someone who actually helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create dynamic sql for that,

Here is a simple example of `select` for that.

```
 SET @s = CONCAT('select current_date() "',CURRENT_DATE(),'"' );
 PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
 EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: Thanks DEarth - i will try this. Does dynamic work in views though

Comment: so how will i be able to have a whole year, example january-2018 end as feb-2018 end as march-2018,   I am creating a type of pivot table and each case statement should end as that selected month. I cannot hard code is as i am pulling last 6 months from current year and last six month from previous year

Comment: SET @101 = CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-',MONTH(CURDATE()));

SELECT `AccountLink` AS @101  FROM  `Accounts`;

Comment: SET @101 = CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-',MONTH(CURDATE()));

SELECT `AccountLink` AS @101  FROM  `Accounts`; Something like this

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%b-%Y')` will do